# Support a custom instruction in RISC-V simulator

Tags: inline-assembly, riscv

I've developed a RISC-V  CPU simulator that only supports the base instruction set("I" extension). Now for a test, I need to make my simulator support a custom instruction. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it except to add the custom instruction to the RISC-V GNU-GCC toolchain. Because I only need this instruction once for a test and I won't need it anymore. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do it in machine code.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thanks for your comment. Could you please guide me on how I can do it? I know that I should use inline-assembly in my c code to emit the opcode of a custom instruction. but I don't know how I can manipulate the rs1 and rs2 in the instruction binary code.

Comment: Write some assembly and insert a line using `.word xxx` where xxx is the hand assembled machine code for the instruction you want to test.  Or make a whole program file in binary, whatever your simulator accepts.

Comment: @ErikEidt: I seem to recall reading about GAS supporting a `.inst` syntax that could put together the pieces of a custom encoding, so you could maybe still use register names with a custom opcode.  (Handy for inline asm so you can use `"r"` constraints instead of hard-coding register numbers.)  For a one-off, yeah for sure just use `.word` and use `register int r1 asm("x1");` to force `"r"(r1)` to pick `x1` for example.

Comment: @ErikEidt let's say I want to have ```Inst %a0, %a1```. I just know the opcode of ```Inst```, and the instruction also requires 2 registers that I don't want to hard code them.

Comment: You can use expressions in `.word xxx`, so that could incorporate compile-time  constants (e.g. via macro parameters or just different `.word ` statements) to use different registers.  Though I thought you just wanted one instruction for a test.